# How can my JMeter Beanshell script determine if it's running interactively?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

In JMeter, when using a Beanshell script, is there a way to determine if I'm running my *.jmx file in the GUI vs on the command line?  Is there a way to know if I'm running it interactively?

Comment: In command line you can add extra special property to identify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code call:

> org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getInstance()

if it returns null, you’re in Non Gui mode otherwise you’re in Gui mode

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/gui/GuiPackage.html#getInstance--